# How can I create this shape in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a shape like but purely in CSS. Is it possible? How?
Many thanks,
[image]

Comment: Check this out: http://www.css3shapes.com/

Comment: Yes, It's just triangle + rectangle

Comment: Thanks for the link, but this shape doesn't seem to be in there so I guess this is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#shape
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 40px blue;
    border-left: solid 40px transparent;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FTu6R/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 .shape { 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 50px; 
    background: #000;
    margin: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

.shape:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border: 25px solid #f00;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
}
```

P.S: Kept red triangle for demo purposes

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y6J7V/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
<style>


h1.elaborate{
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    margin:0 150px;/*15 being the width of the arrows*/
    padding:0 55px;
    background:red;
    color:white;
    position:relative;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
h1.elaborate:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    height:50px;
    margin-left:-25px;
    border-top: 50px solid red; border-left: 50px solid transparent;

}
h1.elaborate:before{left:-25px;}

</style>



</head>

<body>
<h1 class="elaborate">I am the elaborate title</h1>
</body>
```